# Prove that the largest singular value of a matrix is greater than the largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\sigma_1$ be the largest singular value of the matrix $A = (a_{ij})$.  Show that $\sigma_1 >= \lambda_{max}$, where $\lambda_{max}$ denotes the largest eigenvalue of $A$, and that $\sigma_1 \geq |a_{ij}|_{max}$.

$A$ must be a square matrix, otherwise it would not have any eigenvalues.  One of the problems that I have worked so far includes a square matrix, and the above statement holds true for that problem.

I am unsure of how to approach proving this for the general case however.  I know that $\sigma_1 = \sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A^TA)}$.

Is there a relationship between $\lambda_{max}(A^TA)$ and $\lambda_{max}(A)$ that can be leveraged to prove this?

Comment: The answer to this is in :
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244743/singular-value-proofs

Answer (score 3):

The idea mainly comes from '***Matrix analysis***' in chapter 5 by Roger A.Horn

Let *A* be the matrix we will study

1. prove the **spectral radius** ≤ the **matrix norm**.
2. the spectral norm defined as the largest singular value of *A* is also a type of matrix norm.
3. from 1 and 2, the **spectral norm**  ≥ **spectral radius**

so $$\sigma_{max} ≥ |\lambda_{max}|$$

and if *A* is nonsingular, $$\sigma_{min} ≤ |\lambda_{min}|$$

Comment: In case $A$ is singular, $\sigma_{min}=|\lambda_{min}|=\det {A} = 0$.