# Show that the largest singular value dominates all eigenvalues(any matrix A)

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I've read both of
[Prove that the largest singular value of a matrix is greater than the largest eigenvalue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019094/prove-that-the-largest-singular-value-of-a-matrix-is-greater-than-the-largest-ei) and [Singular value proofs 2.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244743/singular-value-proofs)

However, [the later question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244743/singular-value-proofs) is asked about nonsingular matrix A.
And in my case the question is about general case(any matrix A).

I'm reading the following file *containing the proof*:
http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.095/2016IAP/lec2/SVD_Notes.pdf
page 389, (9th page), section "worked examples", example 7.1.B

But I need more detailed explanations in:

$$\left\lVert A\mathbf x \right\rVert = \left\lVert U\Sigma V^T\mathbf x \right\rVert=\left\lVert \Sigma V^T\mathbf x \right\rVert \le \sigma_1\left\lVert  V^T\mathbf x \right\rVert=\sigma_1\left\lVert  \mathbf x \right\rVert$$

the tricky part for me is:

$$\left\lVert \Sigma V^T\mathbf x \right\rVert \le \sigma_1\left\lVert  V^T\mathbf x \right\rVert$$

Maybe I'm just tired, but I can't understand **why this inequality is true**.

$\Sigma$ is m by n(matrix of singular values), $\sigma_1$ is the largest singular value of A. A is m by n, V is n by n, U is m by m.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to clarify the "tricky part," $\Sigma$ is a "diagonalized" matrix containing the singular values $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, ... $\sigma_n$ where by the problem statement we take $\sigma_1$ to be the largest of these values $\left(\sigma_1\geq\sigma_2\geq\dots\geq\sigma_n\geq 0\right)$.   The vector $V^T \bf{x}$ is then multiplied by the diagonal matrix $\Sigma$ such that \begin{align*}
\left\Vert\Sigma V^T \textbf{x}\right\Vert &= \left\Vert\begin{pmatrix} \sigma_1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_2 &\dots &0   \\ \vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 &0& \dots & \sigma_n  \end{pmatrix} V^T \textbf{x}\right\Vert \\
& \leq \left\Vert\begin{pmatrix} \sigma_1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_1 &\dots &0   \\ \vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 &0& \dots & \sigma_1  \end{pmatrix} V^T \textbf{x}\right\Vert
\\
&= \left\Vert\sigma_1\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 &\dots &0   \\ \vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 &0& \dots & 1  \end{pmatrix} V^T \textbf{x}\right\Vert
\\
&= \vert\sigma_1\vert\left\Vert V^T\textbf{x}\right\Vert
\\
&=\sigma_1 \left\Vert V^T\textbf{x}\right\Vert
\end{align*}

I hope this helps you understand the proof.