# How can I derive this bound for the spectral radius of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, similar-matrices

Suppose that $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$, such that $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$ (its largest eigenvalue in magnitude) and $\bar\sigma(A)$ is the largest singular value of $A$. How can I show that $$\rho(A) \leq \inf_{\det(D) \neq 0} \bar\sigma(DAD^{-1})$$ for invertible matrices $D \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$? I'm aware that $A$ and $DAD^{-1}$ have the same spectral radius because they are similar, but I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: Seems like you just need to prove that $\rho(A)\leq \overline{\sigma}(A)$. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Yanko yes, but how does this help?

Comment: Because then you get that $\rho(DAD^{-1})\leq \overline{\sigma}(DAD^{-1})$, but you just noted that $\rho(A)=\rho(DAD^{-1})$. So here you get that $$\rho(A)\leq \overline{\sigma}(DAD^{-1})$$ for all invertible $D$ which should give the inequality you desire.

Comment: @Yanko just to check my understanding, the inequalities $$\rho(A)\leq \overline{\sigma}(DAD^{-1})$$ and $$\rho(A) \leq \inf_{\det(D) \neq 0} \bar\sigma(DAD^{-1})$$ are equivalent, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is if you know the first inequality for all invertible $D$.

Comment: @Yanko I see. Actually, this must mean that (by definition of $\inf$) $$\rho(A) \leq \inf_{\det(D) \neq 0} \bar\sigma(DAD^{-1}) \leq \bar\sigma(DAD^{-1})$$ right?

Comment: Yes, but this alone is not useful. What you need is that if $\rho(A)\leq \overline{\sigma}(DAD^{-1})$ for all invertible $D$, then $\rho(A)\leq \inf_{D} \overline{\sigma}(DAD^{-1})$.

Comment: @Yanko got it. Thanks! Feel free to post an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma 1: For any matrix $A$ we have $\rho(A)\leq \overline{\sigma}(A)$.

Proof: see [Prove that the largest singular value of a matrix is greater than the largest eigenvalue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019094/prove-that-the-largest-singular-value-of-a-matrix-is-greater-than-the-largest-ei).

Lemma 2: If $D$ is invertible, then $\rho(DAD^{-1}) = \rho(A)$.

Proof: Similar matrices have the same spectral value.

We deduce that for any invertible $D$ we have
$$\rho(A)=\rho(DAD^{-1}) \leq \overline{\sigma}(DAD^{-1})$$
It follows that
$$\rho(A)\leq \inf_{det(D)\not=0} \overline{\sigma}(DAD^{-1}),$$ as desired.