# How to prove tr($Z^TZ$) is the sum of singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Ask a maybe trivious question:
We know the product of singular values is |determinant of tha matrix| as in:
[Singular value proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244743/singular-value-proofs)

Then how to prove:

$tr(Z^TZ)^{1/2}$ $=\sigma_1(Z) +...+ \sigma_r(Z) $?  where $r$ is the rank of $Z$

thanks

Comment: No, the product of singular values is the absolute value of the determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be interpreted as $$\text{tr}\left((Z^T Z)^{1/2}\right) = \ldots$$ not
 $$\left(\text{tr}(Z^T Z)\right)^{1/2} = \ldots$$  The singular values are the nonzero eigenvalues of $(Z^T Z)^{1/2}$, i.e. the positive semidefinite square root
of $Z^T Z$.  The trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues.

Comment: I see, from the derivation of SVD.